# Loading pdf in WebView is slow and has an incorrect size

Tags: performance, pdf, webview

I use this code to render pdf's in a webview:

```
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs=true;
        webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new PDFWebViewClient());
        string pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
        webView.LoadUrl ("http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url="+pdf);
        webView.Invalidate ();
```

The problem is that the pdf is cut off and doesn't fill the width of the webView.
Also the scrolling is very laggy

the webviewclient (inner class):

```
class PDFWebViewClient : WebViewClient 
{

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

the application output/console shows this when scrolling:

```
[webclipboard] clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41bf5db8
WIDTHSCALE 1.25
[WML_SISO] InitPasteboardJni
[SlidingMenu] setting padding
[CustomViewBehind] behind INVISIBLE
[OpenGLRenderer] Flushing caches (mode 0)
[GATE] <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
[skia] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx clip not implemented
[skia] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx clip not implemented
[skia] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx clip not implemented
[skia] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx clip not implemented
```